# Coverting Eclipse Project to Maven Project loses Button Link

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat, maven

I am using Eclipse Indigo
I have the Maven Plug-in installed.

I have an Eclipse Project named squarefour

New-Project->Web->Dynamic web Project

Target Runtime: apache Tomcat v7.0

Dynamic web Module Version :3.0

Configuration: Default configuration for Apace Tomcat v7.0

Finish

Java resources->src->square[a package]->SquareServlet.java

```
package square;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/** Simple servlet for testing
*/

@WebServlet("/sqr")
public class SquareServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println
      ("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
       "<html>\n" +
       "<head><title>A Test Servlet</title></head>\n" +
       "<body bgcolor=\"#fdf5e6\">\n" +
       "<h1>Square</h1>\n" +
       convert(request.getParameter("param")) +
       "</body></html>");
  }  
  public String convert (String x)
 {
  int z;
  try
  {
      z = Integer.parseInt(x);
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
          return "Input not an Integer";
      }
      z = z*z;
      Integer y = new Integer(z);
      return y.toString();
  }
}
```

and then
WebContent->index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<head>
    <meta name=viewprt content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-role=page id=home>
    <div data-role=header>
            <h1>Number Fun</h1>
     </div>
<form action=sqr>
    <div data-role=content>
        <span> Integer </span>
        <input type="text" name="param" value="3" />
    </div>
    <div data-role=content>
        <input type="submit" data-role=button value="Square">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am then also using Tomcat 7.0
When I run index.jsp on the server.
I can enter my number, press the button, and the second page is loaded displaying the squared number (or error message).

But when I right click the project and Configure-> Maven Project
everything runs its tool, the square package becomes a folder. and pom.xml creates in the main project folder.

The problem is now when I run index.jsp on the server, the first webpage displays, but when I press the Submit button

HTTP Status 404 - /square4b/sqr

---

type Status report

message /square4b/sqr

description The requested resource (/square4b/sqr) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28

Displays. So something is breaking between the Eclipse to Maven Conversion. Am I missing a step, or is there an error in one of the documents that is causing a problem? i've repeated this four time and the error reproduces each time. Is it because I lack a web.xml file? I know Tomcat 7.0 doesn't need it with a dynamic web module version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

When converting to a Maven Project from a Dynamic Web Project, The packaging needs to be changed from a .jar to a .pom